# compare current datetime between 2 date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my code:

```
declare @fdate varchar(50)
declare @tdate varchar(50)
declare @diff  int 
declare @CalFromdate datetime
declare @CalTodate datetime

set @diff = 360
set @fdate = '2016-12-19 09:30:00'

set @CalFromdate = DATEADD(mi,@diff,CONVERT(DATETIME, @fdate))
print @CalFromdate

set @CalTodate = DATEADD(mi,@diff,CONVERT(DATETIME, @tdate))
print @CalTodate
```

gives me `Dec 19 2016  3:30PM` as fromdate

I don't want this format.

Either '2016-12-19 09:30:00' or '2016-12-19 09:30:00:0000'. I want to compare my current date `getdate()` with 2 dates. If I use above output format with my gatedate format, will it work or both should be in same format?

Comment: Dates should never have a format, they should be dates (parameter types `date`/`datetime`).

Comment: The format of a date/time is a presentation layer concept, it is strictly for humans as that is how we perceive the world around us including information. A date/time is actually a specific point in time, do not think of it as having a format because it does not. So the only point at which you should care about how a date/time is displayed is when it is output to a human, other than that if your code cares about the format then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` and `tsql` based on the syntax used.

Comment: what the others said. convert them both to dates, which is what you've already done, then you can compare them . What is output on the screen (in terms of the format) is irrelevant - you can change this anyway in your print statement.

Comment: You haven't assigned an initial value to @tdate.  It is difficult to see what your intention is.

Answer (score 0):

You are only seeing the date in the format `Dec 19 2016  3:30PM` because that is the completely arbitrary formatting that is applied in SSMS when printing a `datetime` value.

If you change your code to `select` instead of `print` you will return your `datetime` value in the format `2016-12-19 15:30:00.000` but again, this is just an arbitrary formatting used to display a type of data.

Within your query, your `datetime` value doesn't actually have a format.  It is simply a date and time. Use it in your comparison and worry about the formatting in whatever application you are presenting the data in.

---

As an aside, you also don't need to bother using `convert` on your `@fdate` or `@tdate` parameters, as you have already specified them as `datetime` values in your `declare` statements.